# When will the certificate chain be checked? Mutual Authentication

Tags: spring, ssl, resttemplate

I've set up mutual authentication between a service and a nginx. I cannot to find the code which actually does the SSL handshake and verify the certificate chain.

For context I am using the `RestTemplate` provided by `package org.springframework.web.client;` Assume I have set up the connection correctly where does the handshake happen?

Answer (score 0):

Httpclient does the ssl handshake. Resttemplate will internally use Httpclient like apache httpclient.

to verify your SSL certificate chain has been setup in your server. i would use openssl to validate

`openssl s_client -showcerts -connect www.example.com:443`